# C# Datatable .AsParallel() AsOrdered() not giving data in order

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have created data table and store some test data there just to see how **AsParallel() with AsOrdered()** works but when i test the code then i saw i am not getting data in any specific order. ever time i am executing code the order is getting different. so what is lack in my code for which i am not getting data in order?

### see my sample code

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
dtTest.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
dtTest.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dtTest.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(int));

DataRow dr = dtTest.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = 1;
dr["Name"] = "Rom";
dr["Salary"] = "2000";
dtTest.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dtTest.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = 2;
dr["Name"] = "David";
dr["Salary"] = "5000";
dtTest.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dtTest.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = 3;
dr["Name"] = "Samy";
dr["Salary"] = "1200";
dtTest.Rows.Add(dr);


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<table>");
sb.Append("<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th></tr></thead>");
sb.Append("<tbody>");

var htmltables = dtTest.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(a =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("ID " + a.Field<int>("ID").ToString());

     return   sb.Append("<tr><td>" + a.Field<int>("ID").ToString() 
                + "</td><td>" + a.Field<string>("Name").ToString() 
                + "</td><td>" + a.Field<int>("Salary").ToString()
                +"</td></tr>");
    
}).ToList();

sb.Append("</tbody></table>");
```

if anyone run my test code in .net 4.5.2 then must notice this ID order is getting different when i am showing through message box. i am talking about this line `MessageBox.Show("ID " + a.Field<int>("ID").ToString());`

so when i am composing table inside parallel loop then records whose ID is 1 that is sometime coming at end or in the second position. so how can i use **AsParallel() with AsOrdered()** as result ID should be in order ?

i do not want to use **Lock{}** statement because then freedom of multi thread will be finish.

please guide me how to get data in order with multi threading. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsOrdered` does not mean that `Selects` will be executed in the same order, it means that order of input sequence will be preserved in output:

```
new[] { 1,2,3,4}
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(i => { Console.WriteLine("in" + i); return i;})
    .ToList(); // resulting list will always have {1,2,3,4} in order, while console output can differ
```

Also you should not append to the same `StringBuilder` from multiple threads even if the execution order would be guaranteed, cause it is not thread safe. You should accumulate your results and append them. You can try something like this for start:

```
var htmltables = dtTest.AsEnumerable()
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(a =>            
       new StringBuilder()
           .Append("<tr><td>").Append(a.Field<int>("ID").ToString()).Append("</td><td>)
           .Append("<tr><td>").Append(a.Field<int>("Name").ToString()).Append("</td><td>")
           .Append("<tr><td>").Append(a.Field<int>("Salary").ToString()).Append("</td><td>")
    )
    .AsEnumerable();

foreach(var h in htmltables)
{
    sb.Append(h);
}
```

Comment: How to alter my code as a result it should print data table value order wise....any way exist ?

Comment: another small question if i iterate millions of data this way `dtTest.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().AsOrdered()` it will be faster ? or any other way exist which would be more faster. i need fastest way to iterate millions of data. guide me with best example. thanks

Comment: @Indi_Rain it hugely depends. If the processing is relatively fast for one item and result  should be ordered  i think splitting it into some number of chunks and processing that chunks in parallel, can be better then using ordered parallel linq.

Comment: what you try to say that is partially clear. not fully. can you please write a sample code which show me how to split into chunk and then process....this things is not getting clear to me.

Comment: @Indi_Rain you can try generate n ranges for row ids and then use that id ranges to process in ordered parallel linq query (each one will build a string/stringbuilder for it's range in cycle).

Comment: please tell me the reason...why you use AsEnumerable() at the end of linq instead of ToList()?  i change that last AsEnumerable() to ToList() and code worked fine.

Comment: @Indi_Rain you don't need to materialize your query with `ToList` in this case, and calling `ToList` will allocate memory, which can noticeably affect performance in some cases(especially when large amounts of data are involved).